# Как вывести метки записи WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Добавил новый тип записи таким образом:

```
add_action( 'init', 'one' );
function one() {
register_post_type( 'one', array(
    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'one',
        'all_items' => 'Показать все',
        'add_new' => 'Добавить',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавление'
        ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor',  'thumbnail' ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-shield',
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category ')
    )
);
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил в эту новую категорию метки, но никак не могу понять как вывести метки в список, конкретно метки этой записи, не могу понять, есть у неё id или его нет, помогите разобраться

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что именно вывести, где, куда? А эти метки - это родная таксономия, привязанная к кастомному типу, или кастомная с таким же названием?

Comment: Мне не хватает знаний, чтобы понять Ваш вопрос, попробую объяснить подробнее. Я добавил новый тип записи функцией `register_post_type`, добавил возможность добавлять метки `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag')`. Делаю это для того, чтобы в дальнейшем сортировать записи из категории,которую я добавил. А теперь мне нужно просто вывести список этих меток, например через `WP_Query`

Comment: Во первых, сорри - я не посмотрел в код и не увидел как добавлены метки. Этот вопрос снимается. Во вторых эти метки общие с записями. Они выводится напр. в вижете "облако меток"  (или где надо вывести?). В третьих непонятно про категории - этой таксономии нет в этом кастомном типе.

Comment: Если что рекомендую плагином https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ создать свой тип поста и  нужные таксономии, А потом взяв из него код (он показывает php) и немного изменив название функций использовать их в своём плагине для этого типа поста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартные теги в Wordpress выводятся вот так:

```
<?php if(has_tag()){the_tags('<div class="tag">','','</div>');}?>
```